# Creating new chart in c# throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, object-reference

Below is part of the code I am using to create a new chart dynamically on a asp.net page. It throws the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on `chart1_holder.Controls.Add(chartCtrl);`. Any reason why this is happening?

```
Chart chartCtrl;
chartCtrl = new Chart();

chart1_holder.Controls.Add(chartCtrl);

chartCtrl.DataBind();
```

ASP page

```
 <div id ="chart1_holder" runat="server" style="height:95%; width:100%"> </div>
```

Comment: One of your objects is null. Use debugging and breakpoints to find out which object it is, why it is unexpectedly null, and rectify it. Also, in future, you should code as defensively as possible (which would imply doing null checks prior to referencing an object in this way).

Comment: chart1_holder is a div on the asp page

Comment: So the div has `runat="server" id="chart1_holder"` attributes? Or are you 'finding' this div some other way and assigning it to the chart1_holder variable. Show the code which declares chart1_holder please. Anything after `chart1_holder.Controls.Add(chartCtrl);` you can safely delete from the OP, we need to see the code before that.

Comment: Here is the chart1_holder <div id ="chart1_holder" runat="server" style="height:95%; width:100%"> </div>

Comment: +1 for edit. Honestly, I don't know on this one. I can see your chartCtrl isn't null (unless something wacky is happening in the Chart constructor), and I can see your chart1_holder shouldn't be null (otherwise I'm assuming it wouldn't build). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know at what point in the ASP.NET pipeline this code runs e.g.(Init,Load etc..)? It maybe that chart1_holder has not been initialised causing the null reference exception at the point you try to access any of its properties.